# Defining variables with dependent names

Tags: c++, variables

I want to define variables whose names depend on the values of other variables, such as

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int v_i = 2 * i
}

std::cout << v_3; // output: 6
```

or

```
int m;
std::cin >> m; // m = 42

int v_m = 10;

std::cout << v_42; // output: 10
```

Of course, these examples do  not work but instead just create variables with the names `v_i` or `v_m`, treating i and m as characters.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: How about using arrays ?

Comment: No offence, but it looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel of functions. How's `v_3` better than `int v(int x) { return 2 * x; } v(3)`?

Comment: @Winter Take my second example and replace 42 by, say 42,122,478. Is there no better way than  creating an array that large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an associative map. It lets you associate a key with a value and then access a value from that key.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Example:

```
int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> test;

  test['a']=10;
  test['b']=30;
  test['c']=50;
  test['d']=70;

  std::cout << test['a'] << std::endl; //prints 10
}
```

In your case, it would be a `map<int, int>`

Maps are also known as Dictionnary in some other languages.